# How to reverse a list in an integer

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have done majority of the code. I am required to reverse a list of numbers in a loop .

This is what I have so far.. Please could someone tell me where I am going wrong .

```
# output the inputted values in reverse order            

for i in range(1):                                       
    Integer1=int(input("Please enter a Integer:"))   

for i in range(1):                                       
    Integer2=int(input("Please enter a Second Integer:"))

for i in range(1):                                       
    Integer3=int(input("Please enter a Third Integer:")) 

for i in range(1):                                       
    Integer4=int(input("Please enter a Fourth Integer:"))

for i in range(1):                                       
    Integer5=int(input("Please enter a Fifth Integer:")) 

Number= [Integer1,Integer2,Integer3,Integer4,Integer5]   

while Number in range(>0):                               
    list.reverse(Number)                                 
    print(Number)
```

Comment: I'm afraid you lack any baseline knowledge of Python that we could (or should) work with here.

Comment: Indentation is critical in Python and ... ah I see someone took care of it, thanks timgeb!

Comment: I don't know python, but your for loops are absolutely useless. And the while loop also. Sit down and think about what is really needed to solve the task.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
numbers = [0] * 5

for i in range(5):
  numbers[i] = int(input("Please enter integer"))

list.reverse(numbers)
print(numbers)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many things wrong, here is my code:

```
Integer1=int(input("Please enter a Integer:"))
Integer2=int(input("Please enter a Second Integer:"))
Integer3=int(input("Please enter a Third Integer:"))
Integer4=int(input("Please enter a Fourth Integer:"))
Integer5=int(input("Please enter a Fifth Integer:"))

Number= [Integer1,Integer2,Integer3,Integer4,Integer5]

Number.reverse()
print(Number)
```

first, your loops to collect numbers are useless.  You are collecting only one number anyway.  The collection of numbers could be done in a loop, I just wanted to use your format, and your text.

Then to declare a list, use [].

To reverse the list the syntax is LIST.reverse().  LIST is to be replaced by the list you want to reverse.

I suggest you read up on phyton, there are many sites with beginner information to get you started.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a simplified version of your code:

```
my_list = []
for i in range(5):
    my_list.append(int(input("{index}. Enter a number: ".format(index=i+1))))
print("Simple: {0}".format(my_list))
my_list.reverse()
print("Reversed: {0}".format(my_list))
```

Execution output:

```
1. Enter a number: 10
2. Enter a number: 20
3. Enter a number: 30
4. Enter a number: 40
5. Enter a number: 50
Simple: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
Reversed: [50, 40, 30, 20, 10]
```